# Add multiple rows in Oracle using Java

Tags: java, oracle, textfield

I have a text field and a button. When i enter data and click button it adds only one row.

```
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
    try
    {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","nikshay");
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("create table sbase(person varchar(20),year number(2),gender varchar(1))");
        PreparedStatement prepare=con.prepareStatement("insert into sbase (person,year,gender)values(?,?,?)");
        prepare.setString(1,text.getText());
        prepare.setString(2,text_1.getText());
        prepare.setString(3,text_2.getText());
        prepare.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

What should I do to add multiple rows.

Comment: Well you're only doing one insert, what do you expect?  Also, you should add some spaces into your query, as I believe it would be failing on some RDBMS.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen would u please demonstrate me by modifying my above code? it will be so kind of u..

Comment: Just make more statements and execute them, that it all.  You could even use a loop for this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen exactly!! that's what i have been trying to figure it out, how to add multiple statements?

Comment: Once the first executeUpdate is done, set the 3 parameters to other values, then call executeUpdate again. Do that as many times you need to

Comment: Why are you creating the table **every** time you want to insert data? You should create the table only **once** (usually this is done _outside_ of the application through a script)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank u so much man!!! that helped me a lot, it solved my problem with inserting multiple rows from a textfield, it's so kind of you!!